# URL containing the scheme but not the authority (hostname)?

Tags: url, https

Is it legal (and good practice, and well supported) to omit the "authority" component from a URL (typically the hostname) but specify a scheme  (typically `http:` or `https:` ) ?

For example, are these valid urls?

```
  https:login.html   (relative hostname and path)
  https:/auth/login.html   (relative hostname, absolute path)
```

The expected behaviour, of course, would be to use the current hostname - path (relative).

(BTW, this assumes that the `//` after the scheme is part of the authority (host) component, I think this is the right intepretation)

The motivation is the (common) requirement that some pages of a website are to be accesed via https and other via http, and we'd like to use relative urls instead of absolute (to test in different environments).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [RFC1738](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1738.txt) the double slashes `//` are part of the protocol (scheme) specific data (so they are not compulsory according to this document).

But the HTTP protocol ([RFC2616](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2616.html)) in 3.2.2 makes the double slashes part of the scheme, so it's a must. No valid HTTP URL without them.

From RFC2616 3.2.1:

> URIs in HTTP can be represented in absolute form or relative [ ... ] The two
>      forms are differentiated by the fact that absolute URIs always begin
>      with a scheme name followed by a colon.

... so if you specify the scheme then it already is considered an absolute URI.

Comment: I looked into it a few years back when writing a simple URL parser.  If you have the protocol, you must have the hostname.  See section 3.1 of RFC1738.

Comment: Huh? where ? I don't see it.  `An absolute URI contains the name of the scheme being used (<scheme>) followed by a colon (":") and then a string (the <scheme-specific-part>) whose interpretation depends on the scheme."`

Comment: @leonbloy That's what I'm talking about. "whose interpretation depends on the scheme" means that the part after the colon `:` is specified by the implementing protocol which is in our case HTTP. And HTTP makes it comulsory. - I linked the document and gave the section number you can read.

Comment: I find misleading to say that // is part of the scheme. It can be said to be part of the scheme-specific-data, but certainly is not part of the scheme name or specification.

Comment: @vbence but RFC2616 in 3.2.2 is obviously speaking of absolute URLs (if '//' is compulsory, then so it is the 'host' component). I'm asking about a (perhaps illegal) relative URL, in which some components are omitted.

Comment: @leonbloy See also 3.2.1 - I added an excerpt to the answer.

Answer (score 5):

According to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1):

- the **Scheme** can only contain letters, numbers, and `+.-`
- the `//` is part of the **Authority**

So:

- `scheme:`    `//authority`    `/path`

This means

```
https://stackoverflow.com/auth/login.html
\____/\_________________/\______________/
   |          |                 |
scheme    authority            path
```

The **Authority** is optional, which means the following is also valid:

```
https:/auth/login.html
\____/\______________/
   |         |
scheme      path
```

The RFC notes another rule:

- if you omit the **Authority**, the **Path** **cannot** begin to two slashes `//`
- if you omit the **Authority**, the **Path** not need to begin with a `/`

To sum up:

- `https://stackoverflow.com/auth/login.html`  **(valid)**
- `https:///auth/login.html`                   **(invalid; path cannot begin with // when no authority present)**
- `https://auth/login.html`                    **(invalid; path cannot begin with // when no authority present)**
- `https:/auth/login.html`                     **(valid)**
- `https:auth/login.html`                      **(valid)**
- `https:/login.html`                          **(valid)**
- `https:login.html`                           **(valid)**
- `https:/`                                    **(valid)**
- `https:`                                     **(valid)**

### To answer your question

- **`https:login.html`**: Yes
- **`https:/auth/login.html`** Yes

Comment: Interesting. I would say (please correct if I'm wrong) that those "valid" addresses as `https:/auth/login.html` are **valid URIs**. But **URLs** are a subset, and they might have additional rules  - and, so, a valid URI like `https:/auth/login.html` is an invalid URL...

Answer (score 0):

After reading some sources, I think that the relevant reference is [RFC1808](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1808.html)

There it is explicitly stated that if a scheme name is specified, then the URL is assumed to be absolute.

It also comments (5.2) that [RFC1630](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1630.html) allowed some relative URL with a scheme name, but:

- the scheme name had to be the same as the current (base), and would be ignored
- that behaviour was only implemented in old browsers
- it's deprecated

In conclusion, the above urls are invalid.